# Is there a way to execute a PHP file on error 500 in IIS?

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I want to execute a PHP file when an error 500 is reported in IIS. Setting a custom error file is easy. The problem is how do I make the PHP file receive the error details to process them?

For example, I want to display:

- What is the error message.
- What file caused the error.
- Which line caused the error.

Example of the processing file:

```
<?php
echo $_GET["errorfile"];
echo "<br/>";
echo $_GET["errordetails"];
?>
```

I'm using Windows 10 Home, IIS version 10.0.17763.1, PHP version 7.3.0 via FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

It is security by default.

In php.ini:

```
display_errors = on
```

[How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that, I meant to display a PHP file which will handle the error.

Comment: Use php frameworks in debug mode. For еxample https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar